# creating tag synonyms

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-synonyms, privileges

I tried to create `hebrew` as a synonym for `language` (here on meta), and was told I must have a score of 5 in "this tag" (presumably `language`) to do so: but I *do* have 5 (from [an upvoted answer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56) to a `language`-tagged question). What gives?

Comment: Does this help? http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81/merging-redundant-tags/82#82

Comment: @WAF, no; should it? In any event, I've just suggested the synonym mentioned in the question: now it works. Still don't know why it didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug that was [fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109632/179) in October.