# Mi Yodeya Glossary

Tags: support, faq, language, glossary

A glossary!

This is for Judaism-related terms that come up on [the main site](http://judaism.stackexchange.com) whose meanings people may well not know.

To search this glossary for (e.g.) `משנה`, type

> [`is:answer inquestion:581 משנה`](/search?q=is%3Aanswer+inquestion%3A581+%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94)

in the search box at the top-right corner of this page and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Note, though, that that effort may be stymied if you search using one transliteration of a word and the word is listed here with a different transliteration.

If you want the definition of a term you came across on the site, please add it to the [list of proposed glossary entries](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3725/5323), and (hopefully) someone will define it.

*To those who follow a link here:* If you see an answer that's inaccurate or misleading, or could be better, please go ahead and modify it if you have the knowledge.

Here's a general format for a simple entry:

> **עברית - english** (along with any common variants)
>
> Definition goes here, or a links to the term's tag wiki if there is one, possibly a link to Wikipedia or other reference.

For information on typing in Hebrew, have a look at [this question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/what-is-the-common-way-to-type-in-hebrew-for-this-site).

Comment: Also, no reason the answers can't cover dissenting opinions.

Comment: Or maybe have an answer per initial letter of the term. That way, individual entries can be linked to (approximately). We'll have 48 answers, but they can all be linked to from the question. Thoughts?

Comment: @neilfein, but they can't become encyclopedia articles. I was thinking a five-to-ten-word definition and perhaps a link to Wikipedia or somewhere.

Comment: That's about right. Notations if there are particular site-specific issues would be nice. On Bicycles we have a lot of pictures, but that's just because we like pictures. Cooking is similar, I think.

Comment: What do the votes signify?

Comment: @ShmuelBrill - Votes aren't all that important here, but like anything else in meta, they mean that you agree or disagree with the definition, or that the definition is useful or not.

Comment: @msh210 Is 48 the max answers allowed for a question? Also, is there a criteria of how "noteworthy" [not quite the right word...] a particular word must be to get its own entry?

Comment: @yydl, 48=22+26 is how many letters there are in the English and Hebrew alphabets, so how many answers we would have had had we gone with the one-answer-per-initial-letter-of-the-term method, which we seem not to be doing. See also [today's transcript from the site chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468/2011/12/25). As for noteworthiness or what-have-you, the way I figure, a word that appears on judaism.se and needs explanation should go here; what do you think?

Comment: @msh210 Oh. Well it depends. My question was based on the assumption that we had a limited number of answers, which meant only "special" words would end up here. If the glossary can be infinitely large, then there's nothing to lose by allowing (just about) any entry.

Comment: @yydl - There's *probably* no need to define words like "mitzvah" or "tzedakah" that are relatively well-known, unless there are aspects of these words that need to be defined. Although the answer with the variations on [halacha](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/597/647) is kind of interesting!

Comment: Im pretty sure I saw this being discussed somewhere, but has anybody asked SE if we can get some kind of roll-over expansion feature? It beats having to send people to another page, and would be useful for many sites.

Comment: @HodofHod, [Does this site have a glossary?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/419)

Comment: Is this question the location of the glossary or is there a separate glossary on judaism.stackexchange?

Comment: @YehudaW, this is it.

Answer (score 10):

**[CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR), CYLR**

A disclaimer, short for "Consult Your Local (Orthodox) Rabbi". For more information see the FAQ, specifically the section on [how to treat advice from this site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

Note: "CYLOR" may not be appropriate in all cases (where assuming one is Orthodox could cause friction).

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734/5323

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3460/759

Answer (score 8):

**אסור — asur, ossur** — forbidden; especially: forbidden by [halacha](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/597)

*contrasted with*

**מותר — mutar** — permitted; especially: permitted by halacha

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/585

Answer (score 7):

**לכתחילה — lechatechila, l'hat'hila** — from the outset (*a priori*)

*contrasted with*

**בדיעבד — bediavad, b'dieved** — after some action was taken (*a posteriori*)

Example usage: *You may not cook it l'chat'chila but b'diavad, if you cooked it, you may eat it.*

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10217

Answer (score 6):

**גמרא - gemara** — The body of talmudic analysis of and commentary to the [Mishna](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589), found in the Babylonian Talmud and Jerusalem Talmud. (More at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemara).)

Answer (score 6):

**יוצא - yotzei —** short for Yotzei Yedey Chovaso/Chovato  — fulfilling his obligation.

**מוציא - motzi** — causing another to fulfill his obligation, e.g. by reading something for him that he listens to.

These are verbs and are conjugated accordingly.

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1352/759

Answer (score 5):

**ראשון Rishon** singular - *noun*

**ראשונים Rishonim** plural - Literally "the first ones";  leading Rabbis and Poskim who lived approximately from the 11th to the 15th centuries

---

**אחרון Acharon, Achron** singular

**אחרונים Acharonim, Achronim** plural

Literally "the latter ones": leading rabbis who lived after the Rishonim

Answer (score 4):

**הגבהה — hagbah, hagbaha**

[lit. "raising"] — (a) the ritual raising of an open Torah scroll before/after it's read from; (b) raising [personal property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personalty) to effect a transfer of ownership

Answer (score 4):

**תכלת‎ - techelet, t'cheiles**

A particular blue dye used for [tzitzit](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/590/647) and other uses.

([techeles](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/techeles), [tag info](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/techeles/info))

Answer (score 4):

**היתר — heter**

1. an halachic ruling that something is permitted ("issued a heter", "got a heter")
2. grounds for permitting something ("couldn't find a heter for...")
3. the state of being permitted ("היתר במות")

*contrasted with*

**איסור,‎ אסור — isur, issur**

1. a prohibition: a law prohibiting something
2. the state of being prohibited

[Related question on Mi Yodeya.](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56224)

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/591

Answer (score 4):

**ציצית  - [tzitzit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tzitzit), tzitzis, sisit**

1. A specific type of fringe affixed to a four-cornered garment. It is a mitzvah from the Torah to affix these fringes to a four-cornered garment.
2. A garment containing those fringes.

See the [tag wiki](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tzitzis), also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tzitzit).

Answer (score 4):

**הלכה — halacha, halakha** —

1. Jewish law, including civil law, religious rites, criminal law, etc. ("but halacha says to do...") *(singular only)*
2. a specific Jewish law ("there's a halacha that one may...")
3. a paragraph in any of various law books ("see chapter 3 halacha 4 in the Y'rushalmi")

**הלכות, halachot, halachos** — plural noun

**הלכות, hilchot, hilchos** — plural [construct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_constructus) noun — "the halachot of..."

**halachic** — adjective —

1. accepted by halacha ("a halachic solution", "an halakhic dress code")
2. in halacha ("an halachic distinction")
3. of or about halacha ("a halakhic ruling", "a halachic term paper")

**halachically** — adverb

See also [halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha) and [its tag description](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/halacha/info), and the [glossary entry for halacha l'ma'aseh](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4134/5323).

Answer (score 4):

**ממה נפשך -- m'mah nafshach, mimah nafshach --** prepositional phrase - *literally* whatever you think

Used to introduce a [disjunction elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination), namely, that no matter which option you choose from a set of options, conclusion X (or question X) follows.

Example:

> [Why](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/49118/5323) should [Vayikra 19:10](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9920#v=10) mention the ger? ממה נפשך: if the convert is poor, then he deserves to take *leket* anyway. And if he isn't poor, then he shouldn't take *leket*!

Example (humorous):

> If you're Jewish, you believe in God, ממה נפשך. *If* you're a Chassid, you believe because you have Emunah. If you're a Litvak, you believe because the [Rambam said so, and the Raavad doesn't argue.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13800/5323)

Answer (score 3):

**מחלוקת - mahaloket, machlokes**

Argument: difference of opinion. (Connotation can be positive/neutral, as in disagreements about how to understand the Bible, or negative, as in quarrels.)

Answer (score 3):

**משנה — mishna, mishnah** —

1. a body of law compiled circa 200 CE (circa 4000 anno mundi). More at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishna).
2. a paragraph in that work. *plural:* **משניות — mishnayot, mishnayos**

Answer (score 3):

**R', Rav, Rabbi, Rabi, Rebbe, Reb, Rov, R., Harav, Horav, ר׳,‎ רב,‎ רבי,‎ הרב,‎ הר׳** — all just mean "[rabbi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbi)", a religious leader, especially one ordained as such by his teacher.

*Plural:* rabbonim, rabbanim, rabbeim, rebbeim, rabanim, רביים,‎ רבנים

(There are some slight differences among these terms. "Rebbe" is often reserved for a hasidic leader; "reb" sometimes used as a title for laymen. "Rebbeim" might teach in schools whereas "rabbonim" might lead synagogues.)

Answer (score 3):

**בשר בחלב — basar b'chalav** — *also* — **בשר וחלב — basar v'chalav** —

1. milk and meat together (where "together" can be to any of various degrees depending on context)
2. the set of rules regarding such admixture

Answer (score 3):

**מראית עין — maarit ayin, maris ayin** — [lit. "vision of the eye"] — the act of something that *looks like* a forbidden activity, although it is not.

Generally used in the context of avoiding an activity, not because it is forbidden per se, but because it looks like a forbidden activity and might create the false impression that the forbidden activity is actually permitted. For example, a Jew who keeps kosher might attend a business luncheon in a non-kosher restaurant without eating anything. While this Jew consumed no non-kosher food, it could create the false impression that this restaurant's food is actually kosher.

- More here at this question: [What is Maarit Ayin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7459/what-is-maris-ayin).
- And there are some more good examples on this page: [yeshiva.org.il - Marit Ayin](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/shiur.asp?id=6425)

Answer (score 3):

**‏(מ)דרבנן — (mi)d'rabanan** — *literally* (by) that of our rabbis — (by) rabbinic decree

**‏(מ)דאורייתא — (mi)d'oraysa, (mi)deorayta** — *literally* (by) that of the [Torah](/a/3885) — (by) divine decree

(Note that laws mid'oraysa are generally considered to include not only those literally in the Pentateuch but also many derived therefrom by the rabbis or transmitted generation to generation from the time of the revelation on Mount Sinai.)

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16046.

Answer (score 3):

**עבודה זרה – avodah zarah** – noun – *literally* foreign worship

1. *singular only* – idol worship, idolatry
2. *colloquially [countable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_noun)* – a (false of course) god other than (the true) God
3. *proper noun* – the name of a tractate of the Talmud that deals with idolatry and other topics

   - [Avodah Zarah on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avodah_Zarah)

Answer (score 3):

**חייב** *or* **חיב — chayav** — *adj.*

1. obligated (to do something)
   *Someone who forgot to say the "Yaale V'yavo" part of the prayer is chayav to repeat the whole prayer.*
2. liable, owing (money or the like)
   *If he stole $100, he's chayav $200.*
3. due (a punishment)
   *Someone who worships another god is chayav death by stoning.*

plural: **חייבים — chayavim**

synonym: **מחויב** *or* **מחוייב — mechuyav, m'chuyav** (used especially for sense 1, above)

*— contrasted with —*

**פטור — patur** — *adj.*

1. exempt (from an action)
   *Someone who forgot to say the "Al Hanisim" part of the prayer is patur from repeating the prayer.*
2. exempt (from a punishment)

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/608/759

Answer (score 2):

**[צניעות](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tzniut) — tznius, tseniyut** — *noun* — modesty, quietness

**צנוע(ה)‏ — tzanua, senuʿah** — *adjective* — modest, quiet

Used to describe especially people and their clothes, but also their actions, manner of speaking, etc.

See also questions tagged [tznius-modesty](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tznius-modesty) and [the tag's explanation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/tznius-modesty/info).

Answer (score 2):

**סימן — siman** — sign, marker; specifically:

1. Chapter. (Used only for citations to certain works.)
2. Any of certain foods eaten the night of *Rosh Hashana* (see e.g. [a question about them](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2713)).

Answer (score 2):

**מלאכה — melacha** — labor, work; especially:

1. acts, collectively, that are forbidden on the sabbath and festivals ("does that count as melachah?")
2. any of the 39 major categories of acts forbidden on the sabbath and festivals ("the melacha of kindling also includes adding fuel to a fire")

*plural* — מלאכות — m'lachos, melachot

*[construct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/status_constructus)* — מלאכת — meleches, m'lechet

Answer (score 2):

**בל תשחית – bal tashchis, bal tashchit**

(literally - "do not destroy")

The commandment that forbids senseless waste. Biblically, it refers to cutting down fruit trees, but rabbinically, it has been applied to many things including throwing out food, tearing clothing, and killing animals (for reasons other than food).

- More on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bal_tashkhit)

Answer (score 2):

**השם – Hashem, [HaShem](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/HaShem)** – proper noun – *literally* The Name –

- God (the one true god, the god of Judaism)

*often abbreviated* **ה׳** or **ד׳** or **[יי](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2069/1059)**

Answer (score 2):

**בשוגג — Beshogeg; Shogeg** — accidental; unintended; accidentally; unintentionally.

**במזיד — Bemeizid; Meizid** — purposeful; intentional; purposefully; intentionally.

Answer (score 2):

**מלרע milra'** *and* **מלעיל mil'eil** — preposition phrases (used as adjectives or adverbs) — when pronouncing Hebrew, where the stress is placed.  **Milra'** stress is on the final syllable (e.g. sha-BAT, hav-da-LA); **mil'eil** stress is on the penultimate syllable (e.g. sha-MA-yim, ME-lech).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxytone

Answer (score 2):

**פוסק — posek** — *noun*

- someone who issues decisions of [halacha (Jewish law)](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/597)

plural: **פוסקים — poskim, posekim**

See also the question ["Posek vs. Rabbi?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1098) and the tag [posek-psak-decisor-ruling](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/posek-psak-decisor-ruling).

Answer (score 2):

**ספר — sefer, seifer** — *noun*

1. a Jewish-content or holy book
2. a book

Plural: **ספרים — sforim, sefarim, s'farim**

Answer (score 2):

**מחבר — mechaber, m'chaber, mehaber** — *noun*

1. composer, author
2. (**"the mechaber"**) *specifically,* the author of [Shulchan Aruch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shulchan_Aruch)

Answer (score 2):

**ברכת המזון — *Birkat Hamazon, Bentching, Benching*** — *noun* —

A specific prayer said after a bread-based meal. The text varies slightly by community tradition. More at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkat_Hamazon). See also [bentching](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bentching).

Answer (score 2):

**ספק – *safek*** – adjective – a doubt or uncertainty.

*contrasts with*

**וודאי – *vaday*** – adjective – certain

"There was a safek if the meat was from the Kosher store or not."

---

**ספק ספיקא– *sefeik sefeika*** – noun – a double doubt

A principle in Halacha whereby even in certain cases where one must be strict in a doubtful situation one may be lenient if there are two different reasons to doubt the existence of a prohibition.

Answer (score 2):

**‏(תַּלְמוּד) יְרוּשָׁלְמִי** — **(Talmud) Yerushalmi** — the [Jerusalem Talmud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem_Talmud)

Answer (score 2):

**תורה — Torah**

1. The Pentateuch: the first five books of the Bible (Genesis through Deuteronomy).

- *That word appears six times in the Torah.*

2. *(nonstandard)* A copy of the Pentateuch, *especially* a scroll written according to certain rules, of the sort read from in synagogues. (More accurate: Sefer Torah [Torah scroll])

- *He removed two Torahs from the ark.*

3. That part of Jewish law that was decreed by God (as opposed to that part of it that was decreed by later authorities), including things not explicitly in the Pentateuch.

- *It's allowed by the Torah but the rabbis issued a decree against it.*

4. All of Jewish law, lore, philosophy, etc.: the entire body of Judaism's teachings, whether written or unwritten, thought of as a text.

- *I spent five hours yesterday learning Torah.*

5. All of Jewish law, lore, philosophy, etc.: the entire body of Judaism's teachings, whether written or unwritten, thought of as a way of life or Weltanschauung, or as God's will.

- *Doing that would be against the Torah.*

6. *(rare)* [Tanakh](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/124412)

Answer (score 2):

**הלכה למעשה - halacha l'ma'aseh** - practical [halacha](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/597/5323)

Answer (score 2):

**חז"ל — Hazal, Chazal**

[lit. acronym for חכמינו זכרם לברכה; our sages of blessed memory] — Used to refer collectively to the sages of the Talmud. Oftentimes referred to by default as 'the Sages'.

May be used as an adjective: Hazalic/Chazalic, to describe such works.

See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chazal).

Answer (score 2):

**תשובה — *teshuvah, t'shuva —*** noun — literally, a return

1. a reply letter to a question, especially one of Jewish law or practice
   *Rabbi Schwartz spends a lot of time on each teshuvah, making sure it's correct, before he mails it.*
2. *(in the plural, as part of a title)* such letters, published as a book
   *He's reading* T'shuvos Maharamash.
3. *(singular only)* repentance, return to God

**תשובות— *teshuvo, t'shuvos —*** plural

Answer (score 1):

**להבדיל — lehavdil, l'havdil —** *literally* to separate

- often used when comparing (for example) God to another being, the Torah to another book, Judaism to another creed, and Jews to Gentiles

Comment: I removed @AdamMosheh's earlier inclusion of "and Jews to Gentiles" from this entry, because I don't think this terminology is generally used that way in common parlance. If other people disagree, I guess feel free to edit it back in.

Comment: @Fred - I googled "l'havdil gentile" and I immediately found several instances of the word being used to differentiate between Jews and other people.  E.g., http://www.neveh.org/price/pricesensitivities.html

Comment: @WadCheber I just ran a similar search and found a few examples, too (Rabbi Price's article topped the results). Interesting. I also found [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=vZjIAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA196#v=onepage&q&f=false), which cites [R' Chaim Hirschensohn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Hirschensohn) as not only opposing the idea of saying *l'havdil* between Jew and non-Jew, but even (according to Alan Brill) opposing the common practice of saying *l'havdil* when juxtaposing Judaism and Christianity. So while I don't tend to hear it used that way, apparently some people do.

Comment: @WadCheber I suppose this definition could also be improved by indicating that these are examples of usage, and this is not an exhaustive list (a couple more usages are listed in comments [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62274)). Also to indicate that this term is often used out of convention, rather than being religiously required. How about e.g. changing "used when..." to "often used, for example, when...." What do you think?

Comment: @Fred  - Excellent idea.

Answer (score 1):

**יצר הטוב** — **yetzer hatov** — good inclination

**יצר הרע** — **yetzer hara** — evil inclination

Answer (score 1):

**חזן — *chazzan*** — noun —

1. The leader of any communal prayer service.
2. A professional at that job: usually, one with a good chanting and singing voice.
3. *(no longer in common use)* Any of various officials in a synagogue or the Holy Temple.

**שליח צבור — *sheliach tzibbur*** — noun —

1. The leader of any communal prayer service.

— **ש״ץ — *shatz*** — acronym

Answer (score 1):

**כביכול — kivyachol, kaveyachol** — *literally* as with one who is able

— used when saying something about God that does not apply to Him

Answer (score 1):

**מיקל – *meikel*** – verb – to be lenient, as in matters of law.

*contrasts with*

**מחמיר – *machmir*** – verb – to be stringent or strict, as in matters of law.

*Rabbi Schwartz is meikil on the issue, while Rabbi Weiss is machmir.*

Actually masculine singular present-tense verbs (or present participles), these are often used in English preceded by copulas, as in the example above.

---

**קולא – *kula*** – noun – a leniency

*contrasts with*

**חומרא – *chumra*** – noun - a stringency

Answer (score 1):

**בפרהסיא Bfarhesia, B'farhesia** - Publicly, In Public

Answer (score 1):

**מחלל שבת** -- **M'Chalel Shabbat, Mchallel Shabbat, Mchalel Shabbos** - [One who] desecrates the Sabbath.

**חילול שבת** -- **Chillul Shabbat, Chilul Shabbos** - Desecration of the Sabbath.

Answer (score 1):

**מִצְוָה — Mitzvah** — *singular noun* — commandment, command; specifically, a religious command of God's or any of a particular class of rabbinic edicts classified as "mitzvah of the rabbis"

mitzvos, mitzvot — *plural*

Answer (score 1):

**שבע מצוות בני נח‎ Sheva mitzvot B'nei Noach** -- The Seven Laws of Noah (also known as the Noahide or Noachide laws) that apply to non-Jewish people.

1. Do not worship idols or any deity other than God.
2. Do not blaspheme God.
3. Do not murder.
4. Do not engage in sexual immorality
5. Do not steal.
6. Do not eat of a live animal.
7. Establish courts/legal system to ensure law and obedience.

Comment: I wasn't certain whether that term would be construed as offensive or merely technical, so I consulted a dictionary, and it did not indicate that the term is offensive. (My intention was merely to describe the act concisely, but a different way of putting it is fine if you think it would be less offensive). Certainly, it is not necessary to use that term to describe the act, but, regardless of the term that is used, it is a more accurate description of the law compared to the previous edit. You can decide if you wish to edit it further, or leave the more general form of the law.

Comment: @Fred - The problem is that the word "sodomy" is now seen as highly offensive to the LGBTQ community, and although Jewish law isn't supportive of homosexuality, I don't want to be unnecessarily offensive to anyone, including the LGBTQ community. I think "sexual immorality" is borderline offensive, but it is better than the alternatives, and is broad enough to cover all the bases.  I don't think "sodomy" is necessary to describe the law in question, but if others feel differently, I would like to have my name removed from the entry.

Comment: I understand. If you think it best, you can edit it to replace "sodomy" with "homosexual relations." Either that, or the current formulation is okay, I think. But the definition obviously can't be so accommodating as to give an inaccurate picture of the law by enumerating several specifics while leaving one conspicuously absent.

Comment: @Fred - Since the law covers bestiality, pederasty, adultery, and homosexuality, I think the best umbrella term is "sexual immorality".  It accurately and comprehensively reflects the intent of the law. I don't agree that homosexuality is immoral, of course, but my sensibilities are irrelevant here, the only thing that matters is the law as described in the Torah.  For the sake of succinctness, "sexual immorality" seems to be the best option.

Comment: Would you prefer "forbidden sexual relationships"?

Comment: @Fred - That might be begging the question.  Do you see a problem with "sexual immorality"?  I'm willing to be proven wrong.

Comment: I'm obviously not asking if sexual immorality is a problem for you.  I meant to ask if the term "sexual immorality" is problematic for you.

Comment: I'm also concerned that it might be begging the question (in the [colloquial sense of the expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beg_a_question), for you sticklers out there), but this is an issue with all seven to a certain degree. You can't properly understand the parameters of any of the laws without going into details (though #4 might be even more vague when stated generally). And while "forbidden sexual relationships" might beg the question more glaringly, it doesn't really provide less information than does "sexual immorality." But I'm okay with either choice, I suppose.

Comment: @Fred - ignore the chat invite, it was unintentional.  The other option is to remove the description of the laws, and limit the answer to the actual definition.  That would be less informative, but it would circumvent the issues of wording.

Comment: I think the value of including the basic seven laws probably outweighs comparatively minor concerns over the best language to use to express the idea (though it could be a bit of a minefield, I guess).

Comment: @Fred  We're both being too congenial to come to a decision.  :)

Comment: I don't really think it's problematic to leave the description as is ("sexual immorality"), since, from the perspective of Judaism, it is immoral to violate the law (and moreover, the Torah and Tanach in general use language regarding forbidden liasons that suggests that prohibited sexual relationships specifically are immoral). So a legal judgment regarding the nature of a particular act essentially implies a moral judgment regarding the fundamental nature of that act in that Judaism considers it immoral to willingly violate God's laws.

Comment: @Fred - I agree.  And since the point of the glossary is to provide short, simple definitions, it makes sense to keep things as brief as possible. If someone needs to know about the Noachide laws, this is not the place they'd come to.  They can just google it and the first result will be the Wikipedia page for the topic;  the other results will provide more information from Jewish sources..

Answer (score 1):

**חס ושלום — *chas v'shalom* —** *roughly,* Heaven forfend, God forbid

(See also more information on [its etymology / literal meaning](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10452) and [what it's used for](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10615).)

**ח״ו — *ch"v* —** *abbreviation*.

Answer (score 1):

**נושאי כלים - *nos'ei keilim***

Literally "[armiger](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18590212#18590212)" or "arms-bearer," this word is commonly used to refer to commentaries on an earlier work (especially in [halacha](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/597/5323)). For example,

> [Mishna Berura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishnah_Berurah) is among the most commonly used נושאי כלים on the [Orach Chayim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orach_Chayim) section of [Shulchan Aruch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shulchan_Aruch).

<sup><sub>([source](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18589088#18589088))</sub></sup>

Answer (score 1):

**חילול השם - Chillul Hashem**

Desecration of Hashem's name.

For more detail see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chillul_Hashem).

Answer (score 1):

**באַשערט — bashert** —

- *(originally, adjective)* preordained, destined
- *(thus, noun)* soulmate, preordained spouse

This is from the Yiddish adjective, and you sometimes see it declined for case, gender, and number as in Yiddish: *basherte*, *basherter*, *bashertn*.

Answer (score 0):

**בטל ברב — Battel Berov** — nullified in a majority.

**בטל בשישים — Battel Beshishim** — nullified in a 1:60 ratio.

**בטל במאה — Battel Bemeya** — nullified in a 1:100 ratio.

**בטל במאתים — Battel Bemasayim or Battel Bematayim** — nullified in a 1:200 ratio.

**ביטול — Bittul** — nullification in any of the above forms. Verb form מבטל, to nullify.

Answer (score 0):

**שיתוף‎  - shittuf** - partnership.

- **שותפים shutfim** - partners (often, fiscal)
- **עבודה בשיתוף avoda be-shittuf** - worship through partnership (used to denote worshiping (or sometimes believing in) God in conjunction with another deity). Sometimes shortened to just **shittuf**.

Answer (score 0):

**מוקצה – *muktze*, *muktzeh*** – *literally* set aside

- forbidden to be moved on the sabbath and major festivals; see also [a question about the definition of this category](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13744) or [a whole bunch of questions about this category](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muktzeh)
- set aside for use for a *mitzva* and therefore forbidden to be used for other things

This is grammatically a verb (masculine singular present tense), and other forms are also in common use:

מוקצה – *muktza*, *muktzah* – feminine singular present tense
מוקצים – *muktzim* – masculine plural present tense
הוקצה – *huktza*, *huktzah* – masculine singular third-person past tense
הוקצו – *huktzu* – plural third-person past tense

Answer (score 0):

**קבלה – kabbalah, kabala** – noun – *literally* acceptance, receiving, receipt –

1. a particular branch of Jewish study, often called "mysticism" (see also [a question on it](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4581)) ("he was studying kabbalah");
   sometimes coordinated with [halacha](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/597) ("according to kabbalah one shouldn't...")
2. a mesorah or tradition that one has received from his forebears or teachers ("I have a kabbalah that I'm a descendent of King David's")
3. something one has accepted upon himself ("I made a kabbala not to speak anything but words of Torah and prayer for one hour each day, starting at 10:00 a.m."), or an instance of such acceptance
4. the certification accorded a ritual slaughterer, or the written proof thereof

**kabbalos, kabalot** – plural

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16046.

Answer (score 0):

**מקור – makor** – *noun* – source.

On Mi Yodeya, this usually refers to a textual or similar source for a statement.

Answer (score 0):

**‏(ב)אונס — (b')Oneis** - Unwilling (often used in the context of rape), against one's wishes, forced.

*contrasts with*

**‏(ב)רצון — (b')Ratzon** - Willingly, which itself has two subcategories [שוגג vs מזיד](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1225/440).

Oneis is a Halachic category where the one forced into the situation is relieved of responsibility for the result - sin, financial damages, etc.

B'Ratzon is generally the word used as the antonym for this concept, although standing alone it often has a wider meaning. e.g. תחלתו באונס וסופו ברצון - the beginning was unwilling but the end was willing.

Comment: "Oneis is a Halachic category where the one forced into the situation is relieved of responsibility for the result - sin, financial damages, etc." I suspect this is not always true, but I don't have any sources.

Comment: @Ploni The Mishnah you’re looking for is אדם מועד לעולם בין באונס בין ברצון. Oneis doesn’t cover financial responsibility unless you’re a Shomer other than the Shoel.

Answer (score 0):

**גרמא -- Grama, G'rama, Geramah, etc.**

An indirect cause.

Answer (score 0):

**הצלחה רבה**--Hatslacha/Hatslaha Rabbah

lit. Great or abundant success.

Used as a blessing others success regarding a particular endeavor, or used broadly.

Answer (score 0):

**בשעת דחק -- *bish'as dechak*** (sometimes בשעת הדחק -- *bish'as hadechak*)

In a time of great need. Lit. in a time of pressure.

Answer (score 0):

**פסיק רישא - psik reisha**

An unavoidable consequence of a permitted action, resulting in a [*melacha*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/610/9643) being performed.

See also [pesik-reisha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pesik-reisha) and [its tag description](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/pesik-reisha/info) and [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23529/9643) for more info.

**פסיק רישא דלא ניחא ליה - psik reisha d'lo neicha lei**

An unavoidable [*melacha*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/610/9643) that one does not desire to benefit from.

**פסיק רישא דניחא ליה - psik reisha d'neicha lei**

An unavoidable [*melacha*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/610/9643) that one desires to benefit from.

Answer (score 0):

**תנ״ך — Tanach, Tanakh** —

1. the Bible: the following twenty-four books: Genesis, Exodus, Leviticus, Numbers, Deuteronomy, Joshua, Judges, Samuel, Kings, Isaiah, Jeremiah, Ezekiel, the Twelve, Psalms, Proverbs, Job, Canticles, Ruth, Lamentations, Ecclesiastes, Esther, Daniel, Ezra, and Chronicles
2. *(colloquially)* a copy thereof

Answer (score -1):

B"H

פסקין = Pawskin = Paskin = Poskin: To decide a huhluhchuh {or "halacha" / Torah law}

Answer (score -1):

B"H

גאן = Goyn = Gaon = Gawoyn: A genius

Answer (score -1):

B"H

זהר = ZOHAR = ZOYHAR: the name of the esoteric aspect of the Torah, compiled by Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai, based off of the teachings of the "work of the chariot" and "the work of creation" that have been passed down in part since Mount Sinai, and some even since Adam