# Is Double AA on-topic?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

...I've been wondering for a while; [is Double AA on-topic](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47668/why-believe-in-the-revelation-at-sinai-other-than-the-kuzari-mesora-argument#comment125520_47668)?

Some believe that he is, [clearly](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47668/5323); what does the community think about this?

Please source your answers :)

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Well, apparently I'm also [not constructive](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/17903/revisions).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55465/5323

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [Cnsersmoit notes](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3479/759), Jewish individuals are off topic. What we can conclude from this is non-Jewish individuals are on topic. Since we don't know if Double AA is a Jewish or non-Jewish individual, the question is [Safek](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3488/759) off topic.

However, we also don't know if Double AA is an individual or not. He might, after all, be [a dog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog). "Dog" has the same letters as "god" and God is certainly on topic around here.

Thus we have a [Sefeik Sefeika](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3488/759) (double doubt) permitting the questions to be asked:  perhaps Double AA is a dog, and even if he is not a dog perhaps he is a non-Jewish individual and hence still on topic.

However, the Rama rules ([YD 110:8](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&pgnum=525)) that we do not rely on a Sefeik Sefeika in the case of a Davar SheYesh Lo Mattirin (something that gives out [*heterim*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/585/759)) absent a pressing need. Thus questions about Double AA are only to be asked if:

1. He presents a [*machmir*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3457/759) opinion.
2. He presents a [*meikil*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3457/759) opinion, but then only if you really, really need the [*kula*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3457/759).

Comment: It's also not nis'hapech - if he is a Jew, he is certainly (I hope) not a dog.

Comment: Wait a minute. This is only a safek because we currently don't know, not because the extent of on-topicness is unclear be'etzem. Theoretically one *could* go investigate Double AA's yichus. I suggest you do that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Questions about the Hebrew language or about history or news of the Jewish people, **Jewish individuals**, or the State of Israel, except as related to Judaism, **are off-topic**. If this question does relate to Judaism, please edit it to indicate how.

Clearly he is off topic.

Comment: < *shakes head* > **Jewish** sources!!

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3480/5323

Comment: But Double AA in relation to Judaism is on-topic...