# Help edit "Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?"

Tags: discussion, days-of-awe-project

32 questions' worth of edited content have been submitted for *[Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3591/project-plan-for-days-of-awe-mi-yodeya).* The next step is to make sure that each of these submissions gets a good once-over by someone who didn't do the first edit, to help make sure that the content is high-quality and accessible.

So, please select one (or more!) of the submissions that *you did not do the initial editing on*, from the lists in the posts linked below, and do the following:

- Review the [style guidelines](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3606/2).
- Read the entire post, carefully. Check for compliance with the style guidelines, overall quality, readability, and accessibility to readers with limited background in Judaism.
- Edit the post *in place* wherever you see a way to improve it.
- For any non-English terms, names of authorities cited, and names of books cited that not all of our readers will be familiar with, add an entry to the [Glossary](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3666/2), if there isn't one already.
- Post a comment to the post you edited, saying `SECOND-PARTY EDIT COMPLETE`.
- Edit the answer post here to strike out the edited post (`<s> ... </s>`), so that others can tell where there is work left to be done.

Let's try to get these done by **Wednesday, July 22**, so that we have ample time for the next steps in this book production before Rosh Hashana.

Reference links:

- [Rough project plan](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3591/project-plan-for-days-of-awe-mi-yodeya)
- [Project chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25414/days-of-awe-mi-yodeya)

Answer (score 3):

Submissions remaining to be edited, by section:

- [Part 1: Machzor, Rosh Hashana](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3610/hhd-mi-yodeya-call-for-submissions-part-1-machzor-rh):

> - <s>[Why is the shofar sounded on Rosh Hashana?](/a/3614) (originally done by Monica Cellio)</s>
> - <s>[Shochein Ad, HaKail, HaMelech - why?](/a/3641) (originally done by Double AA)</s>
> - <s>[Why is the *Machzor* called a "*Machzor*"?](/a/3654) (originally done by Isaac Moses)</s>
> - <s>[Why Jeremiah 31 on Rosh Hashana?](/a/3621) (originally done by Isaac Moses)</s>
> - <s>[Why don't we say Hallel on Rosh Hashanah?](/a/3624) (originally done by Scimonster)</s>
> - <s>[How a couple lines in Alenu fit the pattern](/a/3652) (originally done by Isaac Moses)</s>
> - <s>[Why a formulaic greeting on Rosh Hashanah Eve?](/a/3647) (originally done by Scimonster) (*we are considering excluding this; see comments there*)</s>
> - <s>[Why was Akeidas Yitzchok a bigger test for Avraham than for Yitzchok?](/a/3629) (originally done by Monica Cellio)</s>
> - <s>[What is the reason behind blowing the *shofar* from the side of one's mouth?](/a/3664) (originally done by Isaac Moses)</s>
> - <s>[Yemenite shofar not from sheep](/a/3650) (originally done by Monica Cellio)</s>
> - <s>[What is the origin of the *shofar* sounds?](/a/3660) (originally done by Scimonster)</s>
> - <s>[At the end of "*Ya'aleh v'Yavo*", do you say "*Melech*"?](/a/3639) (originally done by Isaac Moses)</s>
> - <s>[Why specifically an apple on Rosh HaShanah?](/a/3651) (originally done by Monica Cellio)</s>
> - <s>[Significance of “Shema Yisrael”](/a/3663) (originally done by Monica Cellio)</s>

- [Part 2: Machzor, Yom Kippur](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3611/hhd-mi-yodeya-call-for-submissions-part-2-machzor-yk):

> - <s>[What's so moving about *Kol Nidrei*?](/a/3618) (originally done by msh210)</s>
> - <s>[Why did Yonah run away?](/a/3615) (originally done by Monica Cellio)</s>
> - <s>[Is there tashlumin for n'ila?](/a/3625) (originally done by Scimonster)</s>
> - <s>[*Avinu Malkeinu* - middle verses said out loud by the *Chazan*](/a/3658) (originally done by Isaac Moses)</s>
> - <s>[Why do we read Yona on Yom Kippur?](/a/3661) (originally done by Scimonster)</s>
> - <s>[What does “*Baruch shem k'vod malchuso l'olam vaed*” mean?](/a/3630) (originally done by Isaac Moses)</s>

- [Part 3, halacha and how-tos](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3612/hhd-mi-yodeya-call-for-submissions-part-3-halacha-and-how-tos):

> - <s>[Kiddush on Yom Kippur](/a/3616) (originally done by Monica Cellio)</s>
> - <s>[Additions to bentching on Yom Kippur](/a/3662) (originally done by Scimonster)</s>
> - <s>[Wedding Rings on Yom Kippur?](/a/3646) (originally done by Scimonster)</s>
> - <s>[What is the shiur for anointing on Yom Kippur?](/a/3640) (originally done by Double AA)</s>
> - <s>[Why are we forbidden to wear leather shoes on Yom Kippur?](/a/3657) (originally done by Isaac Moses)</s>
> - <s>[Drinking on Rosh HaShanah](/a/3628) (originally done by Monica Cellio)</s>

- [Part 4: themes](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3613/hhd-mi-yodeya-call-for-submissions-part-4-themes):

> - <s>[Is the Book of Life ever really sealed?](/a/3617) (originally done by Monica Cellio)</s>
> - <s>[How can someone, halachically, do teshuva when s/he has offended an anonymous person on the internet?](/a/3659) (originally done by Scimonster)</s>
> - <s>[Do I have to forgive a repeat offender?](/a/3626) (originally done by Monica Cellio)</s>
> - <s>[What can I do to change myself permanently through the repentance process?](/a/3627) (originally done by Monica Cellio)</s>

- [Part 5: Selichot](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3642/days-of-awe-mi-yodeya-call-for-submissions-part-5-selichot):

> - <s>[What parts of selichot can be said without a minyan?](/a/3649) (originally done by Monica Cellio)</s>
> - <s>[How can I find meaning in saying selichot?](/a/3648) (originally done by Monica Cellio)</s>