# Can I help out with the glossary?

Tags: discussion, glossary

I think I would be well suited to help improve the [glossary](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/581/mi-yodeya-glossary).  I don't know the terminology, so I always notice it when I see it.  I look the words up as I see them, but obviously I am not qualified or well enough informed to write the definitions.  I would be happy to make a list of the words that haven't been defined yet and add them to a post of words requiring definition.  Should I do this?

Comment: The glossary says "If you want the definition of a term you came across on the site, please add it without a definition, and (hopefully) someone will define it."

Comment: @DoubleAA - What should I do if I only have one word, and it isn't long enough to post?

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps include where you saw it because context could affect translation?

Comment: @DoubleAA I took a chance and added the definition myself.  I would be very grateful if you could make sure I got it right.  The word is Rishonim

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3718/9723

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest that you go ahead and start a [community-wiki](/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki)fied list of requested additions to the Glossary, either as a re-write of this question post, as an answer to it, or as a new question post. Then, ask Glossary editors to delete or strike-out entries on your list as they add them to the Glossary.

Comment: While this would be a change from the current official guidance (see my comments on the q), it may be a more useful way of getting people to participate.

Comment: @DoubleAA I hadn't noticed that clause there. Perhaps the best thing would be to create the blank entry there and maintain a list of "needs work" entries here.

Comment: I was feeling brave, so [I added the word and definition](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3718/9723) myself.  I would appreciate it if you could check it to make sure I got it right.

Comment: My definition was "Rishonim pl. Rishon sing.  Noun - Literally "the first ones", leading rabbis and Poskim who lived approximately from the 11th to the 15th centuries".  I also copied and pasted the Hebrew words, but I won't repeat them here because I have trouble with the process of copy and paste with right to left text.

Comment: I just added another one.  Mitzvah-  commandment.

Comment: @WadCheber _"because I have trouble with the process of copy and paste with right to left text"_ You and everyone else on the face of the planet, believe me. :) / :(

Comment: @HodofHod I think you mean :‏)‏