# Proposed entries for the glossary

Tags: discussion, glossary

As recommended by [this](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3717/9723) answer, I have opened a meta question for proposed entries for the glossary.  As each suggestion is added to the glossary, please strike it out in the answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Can someone please add "סגולה" to the glossary? [It's used many times on Mi Yodeya.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=segul*) (I'd do it myself, but I don't rightly know what it means. (Though [this helps a little](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25895).))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is opening up a big can of worms, but I think the glossary should include (all!) the roshei tevos in ~frequent use in a beis midrash. If certain abbreviations haven't been used on this site yet, it is only a matter of time, I think, until they are.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6309/5323