# Pesach Questions event

Tags: discussion, feature-request, community-bulletin-board

[Pesachim 6a](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=pesachim&daf=6a&go=Go) at the very bottom says that discussion of matters concerning Passover should begin 30 days before the Holiday, on Purim. This is codified in the Shulkhan Arukh Orach Chaim 429. We are a bit late, but maybe we should make a Community Bulletin event for this?

Comment: Why shouldn't we?

Comment: What  kind of event?

Comment: Do you mean an event listing in the community bulletin (pointing to the main tag, maybe)?

Comment: We have events on the community bulletin for calenderical events, but if we put them up 30 days prior we'd quickly run out of room

Comment: @IsaacMoses an event like we had for purim, and like we have every week for the parsha and that we currently have for 4 parshiyos

Comment: @DoubleAA I wasn't suggesting that this be done for every holiday, only by pesach, in the spirit of the Talmud's words.

Comment: @BabySeal Oh, sorry. I didn't realize that you meant a Community Bulletin event, so the query came off as rather vague to me.

Answer (score 3):

I've created an event in the community bulletin called "Pesach prep (tag list)" that links to the [list of tags we collected when beginning the haggadah project last year](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1505/472).  There are lots of tags related to Pesach so I did this instead of just linking to [pesach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pesach).  But this can be easily refined.

Comment: Note that, for this year's Purim, I made an event that linked to the *info* page (wiki) for [tag:purim] (not its list of questions), and the wiki for that tag included (and includes) a list of related tags.

Comment: @msh210 ooh, good idea.  The [tag:pesach] wiki has some cross-references already so I'll go ahead and change the event to point to that.  If anybody sees other tags that should be linked from there, please edit the wiki.