# Maintaining Hebrew word order when copying from SE to MS Word

Tags: support, hebrew, haggadah-project, purim-project, formatting

When I was typesetting [Hagada - Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/purim-mi-yodeya/1937#1937), I discovered that, at least in most cases, when I copied text from posts here on Mi Yodeya Meta into MS Word, my typesetting tool of choice, the order of words in Hebrew text is reversed. Against the clock, I resolved this issue then by simply leaving out extended Hebrew quotations.

Now, getting ready to work on [Purim - Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1906/purim-mi-yodeya-book-next-steps), I'd much prefer to keep Hebrew quotations intact, if possible. I just verified that I still have this problem by attempting to copy from [this post for the Purim book](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1944/2).

**Is there a convenient way to copy Hebrew text from SE into MS Word without messing up the word order? I'm open to techniques to be applied in Word, to be applied to the SE posts, or anything in between.**

Comment: You might also try this question at [superuser.se](http://superuser.com).

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thanks! [Done.](http://superuser.com/questions/720977/maintaining-word-order-when-copying-hebrew-from-and-se-site-to-ms-word)

Comment: Any chance you're using a Mac? They're [known](https://discussions.apple.com/message/20599835#20599835) to have an issue with RTL languages in MS Word.

Comment: I assume you solved this, from the fact that you've edited four books now, but  don't see an accepted answer on your Super User question.  Do you have an answer you can add here?