# Chanukah Publication Introduction

Tags: discussion, chanuka-project

Please write an introduction for the [Chanukah Publication](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2115).

Feel free to borrow ideas from the [Hagada's introduction](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1550), or the [Purim book's](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1932).

**Important:** The body of your answer should contain *only* the proposed content, ready for import into the final document.  Use comments for any additional information.

**Voting:** If you down-vote a submission, *please* leave a comment saying what needs to be changed.  Or edit; this is meant to be collaborative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What should I do as the Chanukah lights burn?

**Jews around the world ask:** I just lit my *menorah* and sang all the songs. What now? Fried foods and games of chance are fun, but what can I do to really make my Chanukah meaningful?

**We suggest:** Nothing goes better with menorah light than the light of learning. Why not spend some time each night learning more about Chanukah?

In this book, we present eight self-contained, two-sided pages - one for each day of Chanukah - full of questions and answers about every aspect of the holiday. *Chanukah - Mi Yodeya?* has something for everyone: Practical advice, *Halacha* (Jewish law), history, and more! In general, we tried to make the front page for each day as accessible 
to the whole Chanukah-celebrating public as possible, putting more in-depth content on the second page.

The questions and answers all come from Mi Yodeya, the awesome online Jewish Q&A community on the Stack Exchange network.

Here’s what makes it awesome: all the sharing. One person thinks of an interesting question and puts it out there. A couple of others think of sources that help address that question and share those. Still others vote the best stuff up and the worst down. A spark from here, some oil from there, and a little wick-trimming come together to ignite a blazing beacon of Jewish knowledge, lit in concert by a bunch of people who might not even know each other, up there on the web for everyone to enjoy. And this happens over and over and over, so that after Mi Yodeya’s first few years, we have a collection of over 11,000 answered questions for the world to read.

If you want to get in on the knowledge-sharing, come visit us! You can start with one of the questions used in this book by following the link in the footnotes, or come straight to our homepage at mi.yodeya.com to see what people have been asking and answering most recently and to post your own questions and answers.

As you read, imagine that you’re wading into a crowd of Jews chatting about Judaism around the menorah. They may pronounce Hebrew differently from each other or even use different spellings for “Ḥănukkāh,” but that doesn’t stop them from learning from each other! On the other hand, when it comes to practice, they’re each going to follow their own traditions and consult their own rabbis for guidance on matters of Jewish law; we encourage you to do the same.

Have a Happy Chanukah!

The Mi Yodeya Community

Chanukah 5775

Comment: This riffs on a previous version [by Scimonster](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2273/2).

Comment: Nice!  I like the "a spark from here, some oil from there" etc addition.  Re "the StackExchange.com network" I would say "Stack Exchange", the name of the company, particular as that's not the URL we want people to go to.  (Plus, if you meant the URL, it should be lowercase.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio and Scimonster, I think it'd be nice to include the URL for SE, but I don't see a very elegant way to do it. Maybe a footnote (if there's room)?

Comment: Note that the version pasted here takes up pretty much as much room as there is on the page, so any additions would have to come with commensurate cuts.

Comment: Things I'd like to improve: 1) Add an explicit call to share [pages of] this book with your friends. 2) better transition from two paragraphs about MY in general to the final paragraph about this book.

Comment: The "here's what makes it awesome" paragraph could be appended to the one-liner previous paragraph. Does that give you enough room to add a footnote with SE's URL?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Good idea; maybe. The first footnote on a page adds a couple of lines due to the line above it and some whitespace, and I'm not sure how that works in the two-column format. I'll try it tonight.

Comment: True.  You'll reclaim one line from the partial sentence and the change from SE.com (looking at PDF v4); maybe that's enough.

Comment: I think that the way you currently mention SE is fine .... if people want to find the SE network, they don't need a URL; it should show up easily in a web search.

Answer (score 3):

### What would brighten your Chanukah this year?

**We asked:** Chanukah is such a widely celebrated holiday, but what do people really know about it? Are there questions people have about Chanukah that they would like answers to? How can we enhance people's candle-lighting ceremonies?

**We answered:** What about creating an octapartite book of Chanukah facts, one page for each day? "Chanukah - Mi Yodeya?" has something for everyone: Practical advice, halacha (Jewish law), Chanukah history, and more!

The questions and answers all come from Mi Yodeya, the awesome online Jewish Q&A community on the StackExchange.com network.

Here's what makes it awesome: all the sharing. One person thinks of an interesting question and puts it out there. A couple of others think of sources that help address that question and share those. Still others vote the best stuff up and the worst down. Before you know it, there's a polished, multifaceted gem of Jewish knowledge, assembled by a bunch of people who might not even know each other, up there on the web for everyone to enjoy. And this happens over and over and over, so that after Mi Yodeya's first few years, we have a collection of over 11,000 answered questions for the world to read.

As a Chanukah treat almost as good as jelly donuts, we at Mi Yodeya have compiled a hand-picked selection of Chanukah questions and answers for each day. Each day is given two pages, with the first page designed to be accessible to everyone, and the second for those looking for more advanced and in-depth content.

If you want to get in on the knowledge-sharing, come visit us! You can start with one of the questions used in this book by following the link in the footnotes, or come straight to our homepage at mi.yodeya.com to see what people have been asking and answering most recently and to post your own questions and answers.

Before you start reading, we'd like to warn you: We can't fry your latkes the way your bubbe can. In other words, don't rely on any halachic rulings brought in this book - always check with your rabbi for practical guidance.

Have a Happy Chanukah!

The Mi Yodeya Community
Chanukah 5775

Comment: It's a bit short, only 370 words. It should probably be expanded with a 'leave feedback here' paragraph.

Comment: I based a lot of this off of the Purim submission, as it's newer.

Comment: Very cute "can't fry your latkes" :)

Comment: Stack Exchange: two words, no `.com`. The Stack Exchange Network.

Comment: @TRiG Technically, yes, but we're also aiming for people who've never heard of SE. This way, they can get to the site.

Comment: I'm not so sure about using the word "octapartite" in the first sentence.

Comment: @Ypnypn That's being discussed [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16377/chanuka-5775-publication).