# Should the High Holidays publication have a glossary/bibliography in the back?

Tags: discussion, days-of-awe-project

Our last two publications both made significant efforts to provide definitions of terms:

- [*Purim - Mi Yodeya?*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/mi-yodeya-publications#2013) had a two-page [glossary](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1933/2) in the back that attempted to define every possibly-unfamiliar term or source.
- [*Chanuka - Mi Yodeya?*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/mi-yodeya-publications#3337) attempted to define all possibly-unfamiliar terms or sources on the page in which they were used, either in-line or through footnotes. As a result, certain definitions were repeated as identical footnotes on multiple different pages.

What method should the [High Holidays publication](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3591/proposed-rough-project-plan-for-high-holidays-publication) use for defining terms?

Answer (score 2):

I think we should include a glossary.

One of the big reasons for using footnotes in the Chanukah publication is because we intended for each page to work as a standalone printout as well. When doing that, you can't define everything in a glossary -- it should be on the page itself.

The Purim book, while yes, someone could just print out single parts, is more intended to go all together, and so people can just look at the glossary.

I envision the HHD book to be more like the Purim one than Chanukah.

Comment: I think we should also include an annotated bibliography and index, in addition to any TOC

Comment: We should also have source information, where possible, in footnotes. According to most style guides, a bibliography should be included in addition to footnotes, to list sources more simply.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt what value are you looking for in an index?

Comment: @IsaacMoses, indices could be used for authors of Q's or A's, topical/thematic sourcing, or the like. I personally find indices to be an invaluable tool, although that may stem from me being a current student.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt It will already be sorted by topic/theme.

Comment: I still think indices could be useful.

Comment: Perhaps we could integrate an index-style "p. 4, 6, 10" into a glossary and the credits page. I'm not sure if this publication is large enough to warrant the overhead (work and pages) of a full index.